# Answering the oldest correct answer or the best

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Consider [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182179/31055) on Mathematics. It was first answered by [Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1182181/31055) and then better explained by [GEdgar](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1182237/31055). both answers are correct but the second one better addressed corner cases to explain what I was not able to grasp from the first answer.

As a general rule, is it better to mark the original answer as correct or the one that helped me more?